# How can I handle unauthorized - no token on the frontend in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jwt

I have MERN social media app that allows users to log in and create posts that are displayed on their timeline. It works just fine until the token expires.  In the network tab in dev tooks I get the message:

```
  "message": "Not authorized, no token",
```

The user still exists in Redux so the site thinks I am logged in.  How can I fore the user to be logged out and redirected to the login page and maybe generate a message?  If I log out the log back in, the createPost function works but once the token expires I keep running into this problem.

Here are PostRoutes:

```
const express = require('express');
const {
  createPost,
  getTimelinePosts,
  getAllPosts,
  getProfilePosts,
} = require('../controllers/PostController.js');
const { protect, admin } = require('../middleware/authMiddleware.js');

const router = express.Router();

router.route('/:id/timeline').get(getTimelinePosts);
router.route('/createPost').post(protect, createPost);

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the protect function that checks the token:

```
const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;

  // read JWT from cookie
  token = req.cookies.jwt;

  if (token) {
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.userId).select('-password');
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(401);
      throw new Error('Not authorized, token failed');
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error('Not authorized, no token');
    res.status(401);
  }
});
```

Here is the createPost postController function:

```
const createPost = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { type, text, images } = req.body;
    const newPost = await new Post({
      type,
      text,
      images,
      user: req.user._id,
    });
    const post = newPost.save();
    return res.status(200).json(post);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

This is the frontend function that creates the post:

```
const username = user.username;

  const popup = useRef(null);

  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [showPrev, setShowPrev] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [createError, setCreateERror] = useState('');
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  useClickOutside(popup, () => {
    setPostVisible(false);
  });

  const { data: posts, refetch } = useGetMyPostsQuery(user._id);

  const [createPost, { isLoading: loadingCreate, error: errorCreate }] =
    useCreatePostMutation();

  const postSubmit = async () => {
    if (images && images.length) {
      try {
        const postImages = images.map((img) => {
          return dataURItoBlob(img);
        });
        const path = `tyt/${username}/post_images`;
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('path', path);
        postImages.forEach((image) => {
          formData.append('file', image);
        });
        const response = await uploadImages(formData, path);

        let data = {
          type: null,
          text: text,
          images: response,
        };
        await createPost(data);

        if (!errorCreate) {
          refetch();
          setPostVisible(false);
          setText('');
          setImages('');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('INSIDE ', error);
        toast.error(error?.data?.message);
      }
    } else if (text) {
      try {
        let data = {
          type: null,
          text: text,
          images: null,
        };

        await createPost(data);

        if (!errorCreate) {
          refetch();
          setPostVisible(false);
          setText('');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('INSIDE ', error);
        toast.error(error.data.message);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Nothing');
    }
  };
```

After this line where I call the createPost mutation, if I add:

```
console.log(errorCreate)
```

I will get an error message with a status of 500 even though I set the status to 401 in the backend protect function.

I tried the solution suggested in the answer below but I had to do the redirect outside of the postSubmit function and then I get an error about too many renders.

Just in case you need it, here is the user login function and the generateToken function that creates the token when the user logs in:

```
const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
    generateToken(res, user._id);

    res.status(200).json({
      _id: user._id,
      first_name: user.first_name,
      last_name: user.last_name,
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email,
      picture: user.picture,
      cover: user.cover,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
  }
});

------------
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const generateToken = (res, userId) => {
  const token = jwt.sign({ userId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: '1d',
  });

  // Set JWT as HTTP-Only cookie
  res.cookie('jwt', token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
    sameSite: 'strict',
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 day for now
  });
};

module.exports = generateToken;
```

The frontend doesn't return an error so I can't handle it.

If I need to share anything else please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use a third library to control user authentication, it's challenging to redirect the user to the login page when their token expires, but you can do it when they try to communicate with the backend, for example in the function that creates a post:

```js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Component = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  //...

  try {
    //...
  } catch (error) {
    if (error?.response?.status === 401) {
      // Token expired or invalid
      toast.error("Your session has expired. Please log in again.");
      // Dispatch an action to clear user state in Redux
      dispatch(logout());
      // navigate to /login
      navigate("/login");
    } else {
      // Other errors
      //   toast.error("An error occurred while creating the post.");
      console.error("Error:", error.message);
    }
  }

  //...
};
```

**Update**: you can try with `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
 if(errorCreate){
  // redirect user here
}
},[errorCreate])
```

the effect will fire each time error is updated so we want to redirect the user when `error` is defined

Comment: I tried that and it make ssense but I updated the frontend createPost function.  The error is not showing up inside the postSubmit function, but if I console.log(errorCreate) outside that function, if the token has expired, I get the error but with status of 500, even thought I set it to 401 in bhe backend.

Comment: @StephenScottMoore take a look I gave another suggestion

Comment: Thank you so much.  Your suggestion worked.  I just had to put it inside a useEffect().  So when I call the createPost, if the post is expired it logs the user out and navigates to the login page.

I really appreciate it!

Comment: Oh, lol, I didn't see that one before, but I did give you credit!  Thank again!